# Disabled user / Validation Email

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I've added a column (is_activated) in user DB to add verification email in registration process.

I follow this tutorial: 
[Tutorial](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-implement-email-verification-with-activation-code-example-from-scratch-in-laravel-52-example.html)

It works but an user that is not activated can bypass login function using the reset password form.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should [create middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#defining-middleware) and redirect all not activated users back to home page, for example:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{ 
    if (!auth()->user()->is_activated) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Then [register this middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#registering-middleware) and apply it to all non public routes with `Route::group()`

Comment: Thx, I can't use the default the middleware?

class Authenticate
{
   
     public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
     {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                 return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
         }
         return $next($request);
     }
 }

Comment: @GabrieleVenturini, you can use any middleware you want, just don't forget to apply this middleware to all routes you want. Also, these routes must be inside `auth` middleware group. The good practice is to use separate middleware for that.

Answer (score 0):

If user is activated the value is 1, so integrate in your function the next validation:

```
// if user not have value 1 (is not activated)
if (auth()->user()->is_activated != 1) {
    // user is not activated so redirect to index
    return redirect('/');
}
// user is activated so redirect to account 
return redirect('account');
```

}

you need check is `"is_actived"` have the value 1 or not.

Comment: In my function where?